# The message that appears after casting a third vote in the moderator election contains a <br/>

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, user-interface

After casting a third vote in the moderator election, this message appears.

[image]

The `<br/>` should either be fixed into a newline, or it should be removed altogether.

Comment: I think it would look nicer without a newline, and can repro this issue

Comment: I think bit happens on all the votes

Comment: It might be an idea to raise this in [Main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as this is a site-wide bug.

Comment: @Snow the edit by Catija indicates SE staff are looking into it.

Comment: Corresponding bug report on MSE: [Escaped line break tag in tooltip on election page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331274/335251) – I've retagged this as [status-completed], since [this bug was apparently fixed back in January 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343056/335251).